Is there something wrong with my cross entropy loss function and backpropagation function?
I am doing an assignment about MLP and I can only edit the feedforward function, cross entropy loss function, backpropagation function and some hyperparameters.
And I have to use sigmoid activation function for all other layers except for the output layer.
My training accuracy keeps increasing but my validation accuracy starts to decrease at some point.
My code is
lr = 1e-2
epoch = 100
num_node_1 = 512
num_node_2 = 256
num_node_3 = 128
num_node_4 = 64
batch_size = 4
lambda_ = 0.01

weights_1 = np.random.randn(X_train.shape[1], num_node_1) * np.sqrt(2 / (X_train.shape[1] + num_node_1))
weights_2 = np.random.randn(num_node_1, num_node_2) * np.sqrt(2 / (num_node_1 + num_node_2))
weights_3 = np.random.randn(num_node_2, num_node_3) * np.sqrt(2 / (num_node_2 + num_node_3))
weights_4 = np.random.randn(num_node_3, num_node_4) * np.sqrt(2 / (num_node_3 + num_node_4))
weights_5 = np.random.randn(num_node_4, num_class) * np.sqrt(2 / (num_node_4 + num_class))

def feedforward(X, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5):
    a1 = sigmoid(np.dot(X, W1))
    a2 = sigmoid(np.dot(a1, W2))
    a3 = sigmoid(np.dot(a2, W3))
    a4 = sigmoid(np.dot(a3, W4))
    z5 = np.dot(a4, W5)

    return a1, a2, a3, a4, z5

def cross_entropy(label, output, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, lambda_):
    n = len(label)
    loss = -1 / n * np.sum(np.log(output[np.arange(n), label]))
    reg = (lambda_ / (2 * n)) * (np.sum(np.square(w1)) + np.sum(np.square(w2)) + np.sum(np.square(w3)) + np.sum(np.square(w4)) + np.sum(np.square(w5)))

    return loss + reg

def Gradient(output, data, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, a1, a2, a3, a4, label, lambda_):
    n = len(label)

    label_one_hot = np.zeros_like(output)
    label_one_hot[np.arange(n), label] = 1

    dz5 = output - label_one_hot
    dw5 = (1 / n) * np.dot(a4.T, dz5) + (lambda_ / n) * w5

    da4 = np.dot(dz5, w5.T)
    dz4 = np.multiply(da4, np.multiply(a4, 1 - a4))
    dw4 = (1 / n) * np.dot(a3.T, dz4) + (lambda_ / n) * w4

    da3 = np.dot(dz4, w4.T)
    dz3 = np.multiply(da3, np.multiply(a3, 1 - a3))
    dw3 = (1 / n) * np.dot(a2.T, dz3) + (lambda_ / n) * w3

    da2 = np.dot(dz3, w3.T)
    dz2 = np.multiply(da2, np.multiply(a2, 1 - a2))
    dw2 = (1 / n) * np.dot(a1.T, dz2) + (lambda_ / n) * w2

    da1 = np.dot(dz2, w2.T)
    dz1 = np.multiply(da1, np.multiply(a1, 1 - a1))
    dw1 = (1 / n) * np.dot(data.T, dz1) + (lambda_ / n) * w1

    return dw1, dw2, dw3, dw4, dw5

Additionally, the data looks like this.
train data shape: (9000, 3072)
train labels shape: 9000
validation data shape: (1000, 3072)
validation labels shape: 1000
test data shape: (1000, 3072)
test labels shape: 1000
the number of classes: 10
I changed the hyperparameters multiple times but the validation accuracy always starts decreasing at some point. So I was wondering if there is something wrong with the functions.
